# With p4api.net, I can not load p4bridge.dll

Tags: c#, perforce, p4api.net

With p4api.net, I can not load p4bridge.dll.

I can't add it as a reference to the solution without getting the following error:

[image]

If I don't include it, I get the following runtime exception:

> Test method CFTT.Business.Test.GeneralTests.ddddd threw exception: 
>   System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'p4bridge.dll': The
>   specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)

If I manually copy the the dll to the build output directory without explicitly referencing it I also get get the above error, though I'm running this threw the unit test, so it may be a side path-ing issue.

The above is with the 32 bit, if I try to use the 64 bit (which I would rather), I also get the same error with the p4bridge.dll but at run time, I get:

> Test method CFTT.Business.Test.GeneralTests.ddddd threw exception: 
>   System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'p4api.net, Version=2013.2.66.1822, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=f6b9b9d036c873e1' or one of its dependencies. An
>   attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Does anyone have any experience with these issues?

Comment: Did you build the p4api.net from source downloaded at the Perforce FTP? If not where did you get it?

Comment: It seems that p4bridge.dll is a native library, so you can't add a direct reference to it from .net. You'll need to crate a PInvoke wrapper first. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I just downloaded the libs from the site, not the FTP. I'll check that out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a reference to `p4api.net.dll` - this is the .Net assembly.

`p4bridge.dll` is a native COM enabled library, which I believe needs to be in the same directory but does not need to be referenced directly from your code.

Comment: Additionally you should ensure that your .NET program/library platform is set correctly based on the p4bridge.dll, rather than using the "Any CPU" target. For example, if your p4bridge.dll is 32-bit you'll have to set your target platform to x86, otherwise if you use "Any CPU", when you run your program on a 64-bit OS it will run as a 64-bit process and fail to load the 32-bit p4bridge.dll.

Answer (score 1):

I've posted a solution for this issue that allows you to build p4api.net using the Any CPU target and have it automatically work on both x86 and x64 architectures: [Building p4api.net.dll for 'Any CPU'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893481/building-p4api-net-dll-for-any-cpu)

Hope this helps anyone who stumbles upon this question looking to solve this problem in the future!